# Unity добавление объекта во ВСЕ сцены

Tags: unity3d

Делаю одну игру на unity, где нужно сделать огромное количество однотипных уровней. Если я создам, к примеру, уровней 20, и мне захочется добавить один какой-нибудь объект на все сцены, придется добавлять на все эти сцены объект вручную или есть другие способы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. создавай обьекты кодом, инстанс которого находится на всех уровнях

ИЛИ

2. воспользуйся префабами. Раз у тебя уровни однотипные, то можно создать кусок уровня который будет являтся префабом. Создашь в одном месте, вставишь в другие уровни, обновив префаб - обновится во всех местах.

Comment: ну, оба варианта неплохо звучат. Спасибо!